# qr code scanning not working on Android

Tags: java, android, android-camera, surfaceview, qr-code

I am creating one application where I want scan qrcode but when I try to scan qrcode my app got crash, and it shows error, following is my snippet code and logcat, can anyone tell what is issue with this code and why scanning is not working properly

MainMenu.java

```
 rl_scan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainMenu.this, ScanDispatch.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();

        }
    });
```

ScanDispatch.java

```
public class ScanDispatch extends Activity {


private TextView current_office_name;

// scanning
private Camera mCamera;
private CameraPreview mPreview;
private Handler autoFocusHandler;
ImageScanner scanner;
boolean barcodeScanned = false;
boolean previewing = true;
// private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
ImageView img_navigation_link;

private FrameLayout preview;

public ScanDispatch() {
}

// @Override
// public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
// Bundle savedInstanceState) {
//
// View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_scan_dispatch,
// container, false);
// current_office_name = (TextView)
// rootView.findViewById(R.id.current_office_name);
// current_office_name.setText(consts.pref.getString("office_name", ""));
// btn_scan = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_scan);
//
// return rootView;
// }

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_scan_dispatch);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

    consts.pref = getSharedPreferences("pref", MODE_PRIVATE);
    consts.editor = consts.pref.edit();

    current_office_name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.current_office_name);
    current_office_name.setText(consts.pref.getString("office_name", ""));
    // btn_scan = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_scan);
    img_navigation_link = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_navigation_link);



    // scanner


    autoFocusHandler = new Handler();
    mCamera = getCameraInstance();
    scanner = new ImageScanner();
    scanner.setConfig(0, Config.X_DENSITY, 3);
    scanner.setConfig(0, Config.Y_DENSITY, 3);

    mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera, previewCb, autoFocusCB);

    try {

        if (barcodeScanned) {
            barcodeScanned = false;
            // scanText.setText("Scanning...");
            mCamera.setPreviewCallback(previewCb);
            mCamera.startPreview();
            previewing = true;
            mCamera.autoFocus(autoFocusCB);
        }

    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
        anfe.printStackTrace();

    }

    preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout1);

     preview.addView(mPreview);

     img_navigation_link.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            //  mCamera.release();
                //preview.removeView(mPreview);
                /*mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
                mCamera.release();
                preview.removeView(mPreview);*/
                Intent intent = new Intent(ScanDispatch.this, MainMenu.class);
                startActivity(intent);


            }
        });



}



public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    releaseCamera();
}

public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (mCamera == null) {
        mCamera = getCameraInstance();
        }

        if (mPreview == null) {

            mCamera.setPreviewCallback(previewCb);
            mCamera.startPreview();
            previewing = true;
            mCamera.autoFocus(autoFocusCB);

        mPreview = new CameraPreview(getApplicationContext(), mCamera, previewCb, autoFocusCB);

        preview.addView(mPreview);
        }
}





@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public static Camera getCameraInstance() {
    Camera c = null;
    try {
        c = Camera.open();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return c;
}

static {
    System.loadLibrary("iconv");
}

private Runnable doAutoFocus = new Runnable() {
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void run() {
        if (previewing)
            mCamera.autoFocus(autoFocusCB);
    }
};

private void releaseCamera() {
    if (mCamera != null) {
        previewing = false;
        mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
        mCamera.release();
        mCamera = null;
    }
}

// Mimic continuous auto-focusing
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
AutoFocusCallback autoFocusCB = new AutoFocusCallback() {
    public void onAutoFocus(boolean success, Camera camera) {
        autoFocusHandler.postDelayed(doAutoFocus, 1000);
    }
};

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
PreviewCallback previewCb = new PreviewCallback() {
    private String degd;

    public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
        Size size = parameters.getPreviewSize();

        Image barcode = new Image(size.width, size.height, "Y800");
        barcode.setData(data);

        int result = scanner.scanImage(barcode);

        if (result != 0) {
            previewing = false;
            mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
            mCamera.stopPreview();

            SymbolSet syms = scanner.getResults();
            for (Symbol sym : syms) {
                // scanText.setText("barcode result " + sym.getData());
                Log.d("ooo", "Barcode result:" + sym.getData());
                String contents = sym.getData();
                consts.editor.putString("qrcode", contents);
                consts.editor.commit();

                barcodeScanned = true;

                Intent intent = new Intent(ScanDispatch.this, DispatchTracking.class);
                intent.putExtra("arrow_val", "1");
                startActivity(intent);
                mCamera.release();
                ScanDispatch.this.finish();

                // Fragment fragment = new DispatchTracking();
                //
                // if (fragment != null) {
                // FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                // fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                // .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();

                // setTitle("Dispatch Me");
                // mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
                //
                // }

            }
        }
    }
};

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode == 0) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

            String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
            String format = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");

            consts.editor.putString("qrcode", contents);
            consts.editor.commit();

            // Toast.makeText(this, "Content:" + contents + " Format:" +
            // format, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            Intent intent2 = new Intent(ScanDispatch.this, DispatchTracking.class);
            intent2.putExtra("arrow_val", "1");
            startActivity(intent2);
            ScanDispatch.this.finish();

            // Fragment fragment = new DispatchTracking();
            //
            // if (fragment != null) {
            // FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            // fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            // .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();
            //
            // // setTitle("Dispatch Me");
            // // mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
            //
            // }

        }
    }
}
```

CameraPreview.java

```
    public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    private Camera mCamera;
    private PreviewCallback previewCallback;
    private AutoFocusCallback autoFocusCallback;

    public CameraPreview(Context context, Camera camera,
                         PreviewCallback previewCb,
                         AutoFocusCallback autoFocusCb) {
        super(context);
        mCamera = camera;
        previewCallback = previewCb;
        autoFocusCallback = autoFocusCb;

        /* 
         * Set camera to continuous focus if supported, otherwise use
         * software auto-focus. Only works for API level >=9.
         */
        /*
        Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
        for (String f : parameters.getSupportedFocusModes()) {
            if (f == Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE) {
                mCamera.setFocusMode(Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
                autoFocusCallback = null;
                break;
            }
        }
        */

        // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
        // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
        mHolder = getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);

        // deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // The Surface has been created, now tell the camera where to draw the preview.
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("DBG", "Error setting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // Camera preview released in activity

        /*this.getHolder().removeCallback(this);
        mCamera.stopPreview();
        mCamera.release();*/
        //mCamera.release();
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
        /*
         * If your preview can change or rotate, take care of those events here.
         * Make sure to stop the preview before resizing or reformatting it.
         */
        if (mHolder.getSurface() == null){
          // preview surface does not exist
          return;
        }

        // stop preview before making changes
        try {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
        } catch (Exception e){
          // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
        }

        try {
            // Hard code camera surface rotation 90 degs to match Activity view in portrait
            mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);

            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
            mCamera.setPreviewCallback(previewCallback);
            mCamera.startPreview();
            mCamera.autoFocus(autoFocusCallback);
        } catch (Exception e){
            Log.d("DBG", "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

logcat

```
05-23 10:54:05.760: E/AndroidRuntime(10791): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-23 10:54:05.760: E/AndroidRuntime(10791): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pause activity {com.dispatchme/com.dispatchme.ScanDispatch}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Method called after release()
05-23 10:54:05.760: E/AndroidRuntime(10791):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2720)
05-23 10:54:05.760: E/AndroidRuntime(10791):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2676)
05-23 10:54:05.760: E/AndroidRuntime(10791):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2654)
-23 10:54:05.760: E/AndroidRuntime(10791):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:128)
05-23 10:54:05.760: E/AndroidRuntime(10791):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1168)
05-23 10:54:05.760: E/AndroidRuntime(10791):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-23 10:54:05.760: E/AndroidRuntime(10791):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-23 10:54:05.760: E/AndroidRuntime(10791):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4517)
05-23 10:54:05.760: E/AndroidRuntime(10791):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-23 10:54:05.760: E/AndroidRuntime(10791):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-23 10:54:05.760: E/AndroidRuntime(10791):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:993)
05-23 10:54:05.760: E/AndroidRuntime(10791):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:760)
05-23 10:54:05.760: E/AndroidRuntime(10791):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-23 10:54:05.760: E/AndroidRuntime(10791): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Method called after release()
 05-23 10:54:05.760: E/AndroidRuntime(10791):   at android.hardware.Camera.setHasPreviewCallback(Native Method)
05-23 10:54:05.760: E/AndroidRuntime(10791):    at android.hardware.Camera.setPreviewCallback(Camera.java:590)
05-23 10:54:05.760: E/AndroidRuntime(10791):    at com.dispatchme.ScanDispatch.releaseCamera(ScanDispatch.java:193)
05-23 10:54:05.760: E/AndroidRuntime(10791):    at com.dispatchme.ScanDispatch.onPause(ScanDispatch.java:142)
05-23 10:54:05.760: E/AndroidRuntime(10791):    at android.app.Activity.performPause(Activity.java:4568)
05-23 10:54:05.760: E/AndroidRuntime(10791):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnPause(Instrumentation.java:1199)
05-23 10:54:05.760: E/AndroidRuntime(10791):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
05-23 10:54:05.760: E/AndroidRuntime(10791):    ... 12 more
05-23 10:54:05.860: E/AlarmManagerService(407): android_server_AlarmManagerService_set to type=3, 5838.532000000
```

Comment: What is at line number  ScanDispatch.java:193

Comment: its mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the problem might be in your `onPause()` method of ScanDispatche.java. You are calling some methods after super.onPause(). It should be:

```
public void onPause() {
    releaseCamera();
    super.onPause();    
}
```

This is because Android **first** calls it's method and after it is too late for yours.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();  
    mCamera.cancelAutoFocus();
    mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
    mCamera.stopPreview();
    mCamera.release();  
}




@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        // Open the default i.e. the first rear facing camera.

        if (mCamera != null) {
            mCamera.release();
        }


        mCamera = Camera.open();
        if (mCamera == null) {
            // Cancel request if mCamera is null.
            cancelRequest();
            return;
        }
        Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
        parameters.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
        mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
        mPreview.setCamera(mCamera);
    }
```

Comment: what about onresume??